# How do I create a complete iPhone backup without iTunes?

Tags: backup

How do I create a complete iPhone backup without iTunes and which I can later restore?

Answer (score 1):

The only other option to back up your device is to use iCloud which is encrypted and backs up Health data and other privileged information.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203977